# FastMember usage

Tags: c#, reflection, fastmember

I have a requirement to extract all public read-write properties that are not enumerable, unless they are a string. This is currently done by refelction and wondering if this can be done with [FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/).

I tried something like the code below but it doesn't do what I want. Can I do this with the current version of FastMember?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
protected void LoadCache(IHaveEditableStateProperties originator) {
    var type = originator.GetType();
    _accessor = TypeAccessor.Create(type);

    var members = _accessor.GetMembers();
    _editableState = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var member in members) {
            if(member.Type == typeof(PropertyInfo)) {
                _editableState.Add(member.Name, _accessor[originator, member.Name]);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `member.Type` as returned from FastMember is the return type of the property or method. It should never be `PropertyInfo` as you are checking for in your code. `_accessor[originator, member.Name]` should return the current value of the property.